# Show Schedule Algorithm

Tags: php, mysql, database, algorithm, output

I am working on a schedule page to show some shows. i want the right PHP algorithm to display the shows according to its show start time. Rightnow nothing get displayed.

here is a link: http://tir.fullerton.edu/schedule/schedule.php

and here is my code:

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM schedule
ORDER BY FIELD(showDay, 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY'),
showStart");
echo "<br>";
$i = 8;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if ( $row['showDay'] == 'Monday')
{

    if ($row['showStart'] == $i)
    {
    echo '<td>' . '<img class="newStyle1" src="images/'. $row['picURL'] . 
'"/>'. '</br> ' . $row['showName'] . ' </td>';
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<td></td>";
    }
    $i++;
 }
```

schedule mysql table here : http://tir.fullerton.edu/schedule.png

Comment: what does the table `schedule` look like?

Comment: check at the end of the post for a screenshot of table schedule

Comment: why do you do this?  `if ($row['showStart'] == $i)`

Comment: and what datatype is `showDay`?

Comment: i do it because i wanna fill up the schedule on the page (schedule.php). So its start from 8 (to indicate 8:00 AM) and keeps going but i don't see any values been outputted. showday is varchar datatype

Comment: how do you know there wont be two events at the same time?

Comment: i do the validation before the user do the input to make sure no duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way but it's the only way I could think of...

```
<?php 
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "test");  

$query = " SELECT  PID, showName, showDay, showStart, showEnd, genre, picURL, showURL
           FROM    schedule 
           ORDER   BY FIELD(showDay, 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY'), showStart";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

$data = array('Monday'=>array(), 
             'Tuesday'=>array(), 
             'Wednesday'=>array(), 
             'Thursday'=>array(), 
             'Friday'=>array());    

// re-order the query results so they are easier to use
// ====================================================             
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
   $showDay   = $row['showDay']; 
   $showStart = $row['showStart']; 
   $data[$showDay][$showStart] = $row;
}   

?>
<table align="center"  border="1">
<tr>
<th> Show Day </th>
<th> 8:00 AM </th>
<th> 9:00 AM </th>
<th> 10:00 AM </th>
<th> 11:00 AM </th>
<th> 12:00 PM </th>
<th> 1:00 PM </th>
<th> 2:00 PM </th>
<th> 3:00 PM </th>
<th> 4:00 PM </th>
<th> 5:00 PM </th>
<th> 6:00 PM </th>
<th> 7:00 PM </th>
<th> 8:00 PM </th>
<th> 9:00 PM </th>
<th> 10:00 PM </th>
</tr> 

<?php

// foreach day.... 
// ===============  
foreach($data as $day => $times)
{
   echo "<tr><td><b>$day</b></td>"; 

   // for every displayed hour 
   // ========================  
   for ($hour=8; $hour<23; $hour++)
   {
      // if data exists for this time slot, show it.. 
      // ============================================  
      if (isset($times[$hour]))
      {
         $row = $times[$hour];

         echo "<td>{$row['showName']}</td>";  
      }
      // else show an empty cell 
      // =======================
      else echo "<td></td>";  
   }

   echo "</tr>";  // end the row 
} 

echo "</table>";  // end the table 

?>
```

produces:

[image]

and this is my table:

```
+------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+---------+
| PID  | showName | showDay | showStart | showEnd | genre | picURL | showURL |
+------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+---------+
|    1 | show 1   | Monday  |        20 |      21 | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    |
|    2 | show 2   | Monday  |        13 |      21 | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    |
|    3 | show 3   | Monday  |        10 |      21 | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    |
|    4 | show 4   | Monday  |        22 |      21 | NULL  | NULL   | NULL    |
+------+----------+---------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+---------+
```

and.... if you need to show that something is three hours long or something, modify the code where i re-order things to be something like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
   $showDay   = $row['showDay']; 
   $showStart = $row['showStart']; 
   $length    = $row['showEnd'] - $row['showStart']; 

   for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
      $data[$showDay][$showStart+$i] = $row; 
   }
}
```

** i'm leaving for the day... if you have questions, just write some comments and I'll check up on it tomorrow.